# Easiest way to get textualized binary (0s and 1s) for a simple C/CPP program on OSX

Tags: c++, macos, assembly, binary, clang

First of all, I know this is a very weird request.  I want it only as a teaching aid in a computer class.  It is nice to be able to show an instruction in its binary form to show which bits are going to the opcode, the arguments, etc.  Full hex is ok, but I'm looking for binary if possible.

I am using OSX (Mountain Lion).

I've used the following commands (seperately) to get assembly:

```
clang -emit-llvm -S sum.cpp
clang -S -mllvm --x86-asm-syntax=intel sum.cpp
```

I've used the following command to get some hex values:

```
otool sum.o -tV
```

But I would really like to get a full line of binary per instruction somehow.  Something interspersed would be ideal, but that's probably asking too much.

I guess I could just view obj code in a hex editor, but wasn't confident instructions would align properly in such a way as to make them "easy" to read or understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only speak for Linux but maybe it helps nevertheless. You can use `objdump` to get an interspersed source-hex-asm-output.

Example (sum.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int sum (int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int main ()
{
    int a = 3, b = 4, c;
    c = sum (a,b);
    cout << c << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compile & objdump:

```
clang++ -g sum.cpp 
objdump -d -S -C -Mintel a.out >objdump.txt
```

You can search inside `objdump.txt` and will found:

```
00000000004007f0 <sum(int, int)>:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int sum (int a, int b)
{
  4007f0:   89 7c 24 fc             mov    DWORD PTR [rsp-0x4],edi
  4007f4:   89 74 24 f8             mov    DWORD PTR [rsp-0x8],esi
    return a + b;
  4007f8:   8b 74 24 fc             mov    esi,DWORD PTR [rsp-0x4]
  4007fc:   03 74 24 f8             add    esi,DWORD PTR [rsp-0x8]
  400800:   89 f0                   mov    eax,esi
  400802:   c3                      ret    
  400803:   66 66 66 66 2e 0f 1f    data32 data32 data32 nop WORD PTR cs:[rax+rax*1+0x0]
  40080a:   84 00 00 00 00 00 

0000000000400810 <main>:
}

int main ()
{
  400810:   55                      push   rbp
  400811:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
  400814:   48 83 ec 20             sub    rsp,0x20
  400818:   c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x0
    int a = 3, b = 4, c;
  40081f:   c7 45 f8 03 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],0x3
  400826:   c7 45 f4 04 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0xc],0x4
    c = sum (a,b);
  40082d:   8b 7d f8                mov    edi,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
  400830:   8b 75 f4                mov    esi,DWORD PTR [rbp-0xc]
  400833:   e8 b8 ff ff ff          call   4007f0 <sum(int, int)>
  400838:   48 8d 3c 25 40 0d 60    lea    rdi,ds:0x600d40
  40083f:   00 
  400840:   89 45 f0                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],eax
    cout << c << endl;
  400843:   8b 75 f0                mov    esi,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x10]
  400846:   e8 05 fe ff ff          call   400650 <std::ostream::operator<<(int)@plt>
  40084b:   48 8d 34 25 b0 06 40    lea    rsi,ds:0x4006b0
  400852:   00 
  400853:   48 89 c7                mov    rdi,rax
  400856:   e8 45 fe ff ff          call   4006a0 <std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))@plt>
  40085b:   b9 00 00 00 00          mov    ecx,0x0
    return 0;
  400860:   48 89 45 e8             mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x18],rax
  400864:   89 c8                   mov    eax,ecx
  400866:   48 83 c4 20             add    rsp,0x20
  40086a:   5d                      pop    rbp
  40086b:   c3                      ret    
  40086c:   0f 1f 40 00             nop    DWORD PTR [rax+0x0]
```

The last step would be to develop a program that converts hex to binary.

Comment: This is pretty good, thank you.  I'm sure I could write a Python script to convert the hex to binary and retain the rest of the line.  I will keep the question open for a bit if you don't mind to collect more answers.

Comment: Do you know of the OSX equivalent of objdump?  It is not available on OSX Mountain Lion by default.  Perhaps I need to just find a version of it for OSX?

Comment: @occorled: I've got no MAC, so I can't test it's features. By googling "osx objdump" I found: http://www.electricfluid.com/?p=56.